# change event in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need the total price from ( the base value + logo value + material value )

I had tried this code [mycode](http://jsfiddle.net/vasanthanvas/3of6g4tb/)

**condition**
1) if select the logo type and material type i need to get the total value.
2) if i selected both the value, now am changing the logo value i need to get the correct total
3) total to be displayed after selecting each option dynamical
4) no submit button to be used.

**HTML**

```
<p class="logotype left customLabel"><span>base price :</span>1000</p>
<p class="logotype left customLabel"><span>Logo Type :</span></p>
   <form class="left margin0" name="logotypeform" method="post">
        <select name="logoprice" id="logotypeprice">
        <option value="">--</option>           
            <option value="50">Default logo</option>
            <option value="100">Imported logo</option>
            <option value="25">Text</option>
             <option value="0">None</option>
        </select>
    </form>
<input class="logoTypeVal" type="" value="">

  <p class="Material left customLabel"><span>Material    :</span></p>
   <form class="left margin0" name="priceform" method="post">
        <select name="price" id="materialprice">
        <option value="">--</option>
            <option value="10">Nylon</option>
            <option value="20">Sticker</option>
            <option value="30">Printed</option>
            <option value="30">Embroiding</option>
             <option value="0">None</option>
        </select>
    </form>
<input class="materialVal" type="" value="">
<p class="Material left customLabel"><span>Total Value    :</span></p><input class="totalVal" type="" value="total value">
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     var baseValue = 1000;

     jQuery('#logotypeprice').change(function(){
         var logotypeprice = jQuery(this).val();
         jQuery('input.logoTypeVal').val(logotypeprice);

     });
     jQuery('#materialprice').change(function(){
         var materialprice = jQuery(this).val();
         jQuery('input.materialVal').val(materialprice);
         var baseprice = "<?php echo $basePrice ?>";
         var logoval = logotypeprice;
         var totalprice = parseInt(baseValue) + parseInt(materialprice) + parseInt(logoval);
         alert(totalprice);
         jQuery('input.totalVal').val(totalprice);
     });    

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update:

Since you need the total value to update based on changing each select you should calculate the total on both handlers. Like below

```
var baseValue = 1000,
    logotypeprice = 0,
    materialprice = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#logotypeprice').change(function () {
        logotypeprice = jQuery(this).val();
        $('input.logoTypeVal').val(logotypeprice);
        calculateTotal();
    });
    $('#materialprice').change(function () {
        materialprice = $(this).val();
        $('input.materialVal').val(materialprice);
        calculateTotal();
    });
});

function calculateTotal() {
    var totalprice = parseInt(baseValue) + parseInt(materialprice) + parseInt(logotypeprice);
    $('input.totalVal').val(totalprice);
}
```

Here is an updated [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/x37nfk2a/2/)

**PS**: Instead of writing `jQuery` for each element you can use the short version `$`

---

You are trying to access `logotypeprice` variable which is not accessible inside `materialprice` change handler

Either declare `logotypeprice` globally like this

```
 var baseValue = 1000;
 var logotypeprice;

 jQuery('#logotypeprice').change(function(){
     logotypeprice = jQuery(this).val();
     jQuery('input.logoTypeVal').val(logotypeprice);

 });
 jQuery('#materialprice').change(function(){
     var materialprice = jQuery(this).val();
     jQuery('input.materialVal').val(materialprice);
     var baseprice = "100";
     var logoval = logotypeprice;
     var totalprice = parseInt(baseValue) + parseInt(materialprice) + parseInt(logoval);
     alert(totalprice);
     jQuery('input.totalVal').val(totalprice);
 });
```

Or

access logo value from `input.logoTypeVal` or `#logotypeprice` value like this

```
 jQuery('#materialprice').change(function(){
     var materialprice = jQuery(this).val();
     jQuery('input.materialVal').val(materialprice);
     var baseprice = "100";
     var logoval = jQuery('input.logoTypeVal').val(); // OR logoval = jQuery('#logotypeprice').val();
     var totalprice = parseInt(baseValue) + parseInt(materialprice) + parseInt(logoval);
     alert(totalprice);
     jQuery('input.totalVal').val(totalprice);
 });
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/x37nfk2a/)

Comment: am not getting the Total value , output is NaN

Comment: good inproment thanks for ur effort, but still there is an issue after selecting both the select option i got the total value. again am selecting only the 1st select option (changing the option of 1st select) not changing the 2nd select option the total remain unchanged

Comment: that happens because you are not calculating the total sum in 1st selection change handler

Comment: ya i understand i need the correct coding for my requirement. since am an front developer i don't have much hands on jQuery, could you plz help.